# SQL: removing a date from from inner SQL statement returns incorrect data

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure this one out, but am stuck.

From the below SQL statement, when I run the statement with the commented date, I get the correct result. But when I remove it, the statement returns incorrect data; it omits a few records.

I don't understand why having the date filter and not having it in the statement following the NOT IN produces different results. Also, is there something else I can try other than "not in"?

```
select 
    RscMaster_no_in, last_name, first_name, Wstat_Abrv_Ch, 
    Staffing_Calendar_Date, payhours
from
    all_hire 
where 
    Wstat_no_in in (103)
    and RscMaster_no_in not in (select t2.RscMaster_no_in
                                from all_hire h 
                                right join (select h.RscMaster_no_in, last_name, first_name, Staffing_Calendar_Date
                                            from all_hire h
                                            where rscmaster_no_in in (select rscmaster_no_in from ECC_splty) 
                                              and Wstat_Abrv_Ch <> ''
                                              and Wstat_no_in = 107) t2 on h.RscMaster_no_in = t2.RscMaster_no_in and h.Staffing_Calendar_Date = t2.Staffing_Calendar_Date
                                where 
                                    h.Wstat_no_in = 103
                                    and h.Staffing_Calendar_Date = '2020-11-01' -- this date is only for testing, and will have to be removed. The SQL statement, however, returns correct data with this filter added. 
                                )
    and Staffing_Calendar_Date = '2020-11-01'
```

From the below SQL statement #1, I get 29 records.

```
select 
    RscMaster_no_in, last_name, first_name, Wstat_Abrv_Ch, 
    Staffing_Calendar_Date, payhours
from
    all_hire 
where 
    Wstat_no_in in (103)
and
    Staffing_Calendar_Date = '2020-11-01'
```

From SQL statement #2 below, I get 2 records.

```
select t2.RscMaster_no_in
from all_hire h 
right join (select h.RscMaster_no_in, last_name, first_name, 
Staffing_Calendar_Date
from all_hire h
where rscmaster_no_in in (select rscmaster_no_in from ECC_splty) 
and Wstat_Abrv_Ch <> ''
and Wstat_no_in = 107) t2 on h.RscMaster_no_in = t2.RscMaster_no_in and 
h.Staffing_Calendar_Date = t2.Staffing_Calendar_Date
where 
h.Wstat_no_in = 103
and h.Staffing_Calendar_Date = '2020-11-01'
```

So when I combine these two SQL statements, I get the correct result with the 27 records. It is only when I remove the date from statement #2 that I get the incorrect number of records - 22 records. I checked the records and did not see any issue. I just don't understand why.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have an example of the data that is incorrectly eliminated. Also, is RscMaster_no_in unique?

Comment: I bet the commented date filter is removing records with null values from the right join. When you remove it, the records from t2 without a matching h would have a null value for h.Staffing_Calendar_Date and would be allowed through, with it, those records are omitted.

Comment: @edmCoff - I've added more information about my question. I hope that helps.

Comment: So what's the purpose of your `RIGHT JOIN`?  The `WHERE` clause `h.Wstat_no_in = 103 and h.Staffing_Calendar_Date = '2020-11-01'` turns it into `INNER JOIN` anyway.

Comment: Hi Lucas. Please don't edit in "solved" into the title and/or adding your solution to your question please. You can answer your own question by adding a real answer, and mark the answer to have your question show up as "solved". If the answer is unlikely to help another user, you may also just delete your question.

Comment: Are you using true dates? What about time components?